# Anything wrong with using MTB saddle on hybrid bike

Tags: bike-fit

I'm been having problems with fit on my hybrid. 
When I spend around 1hr on the saddle I start to get pain in the left prostate.

I can no longer ignore the problem because I plan to do C2C. Right now I need to do some training because I'm not that much better than a couch potato. I have a feeling I won't make it otherwise.

The thing is I have two other mountain bikes and I don't seem to get the same problem.

Shall I just get a MTB sadddle?

Comment: Er, you only have one prostate gland. Anyway, why don't you just take the saddle off one of your mountain bike, fit it to your hybrid and see if it works for you?

Comment: saddles are pretty much saddles. if you have one that works for you, use it, regardless of the context of its branding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's very little that is discipline specific in bicycle saddles, so there is no reason to not use MTB saddle on a hybrid if it works for you.

Usually there is a relationship between saddle style and riding position: the lower the handlebars, the narrower and flatter saddle. This goes both on and off road. If there is any difference in saddles designed for these it is that MTB gear is sturdier and road gear lighter and may have breathable surface material. The saddle that come with a hybrid may be any of these or something in between.

Comment: MTB saddles are typically longer to accommodate shifting weight forward and back as needed for hill climbs and descents while seated.

Comment: Do you have a reference for that? The same reasoning applies to road riding too, and is you check actual saddle catalogs, everything seems to be between 26.5 and 28 cm without clear trends in any direction.

Answer (score 4):

This is fine. There is not really any hard "Hybrid" and "MTB" saddle categories. The  cycling gods will not smite you down for committing bicycle components miscegenation.

Answer (score 1):

There are no hard and fast rules - saddles are completely personal to the rider.

The only numbers that count are "width" because of how far apart your sit-bones are, and total weight because some people like a light bike.

Another often-overlooked point is that the pants you wear absolutely affect your saddle comfort too.  Tighter cycling shorts will make your body parts sit more comfortably and predictably over time, reducing chafing.

I personally use a woman's specific saddle on my road bike despite being a bloke, because it was the most comfortable available at the time